# Edit variable in action listener not working

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I Am still learning Java but I have been struggling with this for a very long time.

I want to be able to edit set a boolean after a button gets pushed, but it never works.

Here is an example:

```
    JButton send = new JButton();
    Boolean click = false

    send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                click = true
            }
        });
    if (click){
            System.out.println("WORKS GOOD!!")
    }
```

But the variable does not change.

Comment: You've posted code without any context of where it's coming from.  Where is your action listener defined?  Where are you checking the state of `click`?  The way you've posted it makes it look like you're doing it all in the same method.

Comment: well by the time the user clicks the button the `if` statement has been processed already.

Comment: @azurefrog This is just a chunk of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about it. In Java there is no way to make what you want to do. Inside enclosed object (i.e. `new ActionListener()`) you may have access to 
**final** variables from enclosing type, and only to read them, but never change, because they are **final**.

as example code below works (but nothing more):

```
    final Boolean click = false;    

    send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("outside variable 'click' is:" + click);
            }
        });
```

BTW: it is not a good idea what you try to do and Java does not allow it, because it is not a good idea... :-)

UPDATE: If you still want to do it, you can make a wrapper class.

code below works, but do not tell later, that I did not warn you that it is a very bad idea.

```
public class MyClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JButton send = new JButton();
    final BooleanWrapper click = new BooleanWrapper();

    click.value = false;

    send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                click.value = true;
            }
        });

    send.getActionListeners()[0].actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(new MyClass(), 1, "very bad idea"));

    if (click.value ){
            System.out.println("WORKS GOOD!!");
    }

}

private static class BooleanWrapper
{
    private Boolean value;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `if (click)` condition is only evaluated once, before any button click could happen, and click is `false` at that time. You need to reevaluate the condition after each time the button is pressed.

What is the purpose of the boolean? Why not just do:

```
JButton send = new JButton();

send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("WORKS GOOD!!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: i know but i want to edit the variable after its clicked

Comment: Your code does change the variable after the button is clicked. It's just that the code you use to check if the variable has been set doesn't work like you want it to.

Comment: I want to be able to set a string after its clicked

Comment: @KeionBeats So? Why not do it in the `ActionListener`? You seem to be thinking in a procedural/linear fashion, which is not how GUIs work, GUIs are event driven